# Need to find no of nth occurenece of the day from date in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have date and day. Now I want to find whether it is 1st or 2nd or 3rd or 4th week for that day.

Suppose if I pass date today. Then it should return "1st Tuesday" of the month.

If I pass 18-May-2013, then it should return "3rd Saturday of the month".
If I pass 31-May-2013, then it should return "5th Friday of the month".

How can I achieve this?

Comment: w.y.t. : What you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go

```
DECLARE @date DATETIME;

SET @date = '2013-08-30'
select 
case when DATEPART(dd,@date)<=7 then '1st '+datename(DW,@date)
when DATEPART(dd,@date)>7 and DATEPART(dd,@date)<=14 then '2nd '+datename(DW,@date)
when DATEPART(dd,@date)>14 and DATEPART(dd,@date)<=21 then '3rd '+datename(DW,@date)
when DATEPART(dd,@date)>21 and DATEPART(dd,@date)<=28 then '4th '+datename(DW,@date)
when DATEPART(dd,@date)>28 and DATEPART(dd,@date)<=31 then '5th '+datename(DW,@date) end
```

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT 
-- Do you need this: (DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()) + @@DATEFIRST % 7)
CASE 1 + (DATEPART(DAY, GETDATE()) - 1) / 7
    WHEN 1 THEN '1St'
    WHEN 2 THEN '2nd'
    WHEN 3 THEN '3rd'
    WHEN 4 THEN '4th'
    ELSE '5th'
END
+ ' '
+ DATENAME(dw, GETDATE())
+ ' of the month'
```

Answer (score 2):

try this,

```
DECLARE @date DATETIME;
DECLARE @week INT;

SET @date = getdate()

SELECT @week = datepart(wk, @date) - datepart(wk, convert(DATETIME, cast(month(getdate()) AS VARCHAR) + '/01/' + cast(year(getdate()) AS VARCHAR)) + 1)

SELECT CASE WHEN @week = 1 THEN '1st ' WHEN @week = 2 THEN '2nd ' WHEN @week = 3 THEN '3RD ' ELSE '4th ' END + DATENAME(weekday, @date) + ' of the month'
```

Comment: Please check your code for date '2013-08-30'..It should return 5th friday of the month..Instead of that it is returning 4th friday of the month.

Comment: you can check for 31-May-2013 also.

Comment: Simple, just need to add one more case statement.

Answer (score 1):

Well , if day XXX's number is between 1 and 7, it's the first XXX of the month , if it's between 8 and 14 , it's the second XXX of the month, if it's between 15 and 21 , it's the 3rd XXX of the month, if it's between 22 and 28, it's the 4th XXX of the month , and if it's over 28 it's the 5th XXX of the month...

Answer (score 1):

One more option

```
DECLARE @date datetime = GETDATE()
SELECT CASE DATEPART(ww, @date) - (DATEPART(ww, DATEADD(DAY, 1 - DAY(@date), @date)) 
       - CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw, DATEADD(dd, 1 - DAY(@date), @date)) <= DATEPART(dw, @date) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
         WHEN 1 THEN '1st '
         WHEN 2 THEN '2nd '
         WHEN 3 THEN '3rd '
         WHEN 4 THEN '4th '
         WHEN 5 THEN '5th ' END + DATENAME(dw, @date) + ' of the month'
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/13244)